# TWRP - Redirect script stdout to recovery output

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, scripts

I have a flashable zip that runs a **.sh** script on flashing it via TWRP.
What it does not do is that it doesn't print `stdout` of the script to the `recovery output` (although it logs it in `/cache/recovery_log`.

I want something like what *OpenGapps* or *SuperSU* zips do.

I've referred [a guide by Chainfire on XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1023150), but I'm still confused.

Do I need a different `updater-binary`/`updater-script` like *Opengapps* or *SuperSU* have, or is there another, way for it?

Comment: Does this ZIP only execute the **update-binary**, or does it execute an additional .sh script?

Comment: It executes an additional .sh script